# Python clear terminal without using system calls

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to write a python script for use on Windows and Linux that clears the screen.
Most of the examples for this are something like:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

which works, but is a bit dicey given all of the issues with making system calls (security issues). Is there a better way of clearing the terminal in python without needing to use system?
The best alternative I have found so far was this:

```
print("\033c");
```

but it has the slight annoyance of removing everything from the terminal
(ie I would like it to clear the terminal, but the user should be able to scroll up and see previous output in the terminal).

Comment: Print multiple newlines, print "\n"*20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) should help on linux (and most *nix unless you find a really weird terminal):

```
print("\x1b[2J\x1b[H",end="")
```

It'll clear the screen and put your cursor at the top left. You can still scroll up to find your old stuff but you may have to go up a decent distance to find it.

I have absolutely no idea what it'll do on windows. You may find you need to detect the os and use a different method there.

For python 2.x you'll need to use `sys.stdout.write` instead of the `print` statement as you can't suppress the `\n` on `print` in 2.x as far as I know.

Comment: how exactly do I use it properly in 2.x? I tried 



>>> import sys

>>> sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H",end="")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @BruceJohnJennerLawso, don't use end="" with sys,  you can also `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @BruceJohnJennerLawso just use `sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")` its only `print` that sticks the `'\n'` on the end by default. `.write` doesn't add anything.

Comment: @BruceJohnJennerLawso: Look at the sequence elements [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements). The `"\x1b["` tells it that an ANSI code is coming up. This happens twice in that string. The first is just before `"2J"`. `"J"` tells it to clear the screen and `"2"` tells it to clear the *whole* screen rather than just the bit between the cursor and the beginning. The second `"\x1b["` is followed by the letter `"H"`. This tells it to move the cursor. You can add numbers before the `"H"` to tell it where to move but the default is the top left so we don't need any.

Comment: Any example of “weird terminal”?

Answer (score 0):

If you have special knowledge of the screen size you can use a modified version of your original `print`-based answer.

```
def cls(x):
    """Clears the screen after printing x newlines."""
    print "\n" * x
    print "\033c"
```

In Python 3.3 and later you can divine the size of the Terminal window with `shutil`, but I don't think there's a great way to do it in 2.7 without actually importing `os`, which you said should be avoided.

Comment: that does work, but I wanted the prompt to be at the top of the screen afterwards as well, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Ok, edited. I was half-joking, but I guess there's nothing funny about 65k spaces

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code doesn't call `os` directly from the code.
**Try this:**

```
from subprocess import call
def clear(int=None):  
    call('clear')
    if int == 0:
       exit()
clear()
```

It worked for me, I work on linux but I think it will work on windows to.